# Neo4j create/insert data with csv errors

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher, relationships

I have a problem with creating/inserting data in my database from csv files.
I have 2 CSV Files. 
person.csv with Headers (personID, name, email, telefon)
friendship.csv with Headers (pfrom, pto)

personID = pfrom and pto = personID. 
This is intended to represent friendships between persons.

There are 1,000 person and 2 friends per person (2,000 rows).

Here my import.cypher file:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///friends1k\\person.csv" AS row
CREATE (:person {personID: row.personID, name: row.name, email: row.email, telefon: row.telefon});

CREATE INDEX ON :person(personID);

schema await

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///friends1k\\friendship.csv" AS row
MATCH (p1:Person {personID: row.pfrom})
MATCH (p2:Person {personID: row.pto})
MERGE (p1)-[:FRIENDSHIP]->(p2);
```

The idea is from this website (https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-importing-data-and-etl/).

The output of that import.cypher is:

``` ``  +-------------------+
    | No data returned. |
    +-------------------+
    Nodes created: 1000
    Properties set: 4000
    Labels added: 1000
    889 ms
    +-------------------+
    | No data returned. |
    +-------------------+
    Indexes added: 1
    0 ms
    Awaiting :person ON [personID] ONLINE
    +--------------------------------------------+
    | No data returned, and nothing was changed. |
    +--------------------------------------------+
    312 ms


Now I'm testing it with the following query:

MATCH (me:person)-[:FRIENDSHIP]-(friends:person)
WHERE me.personID='1'
RETURN count(friends);


The output from this is:

    +----------------+
    | count(friends) |
    +----------------+
    | 0              |
    +----------------+
    1 row
    93 ms ```

But the result should be 2 becouse every person has two friends.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

How do you see when you create a relationship no changes have been made:

```
 No data returned, and nothing was changed.
```

It's because labels of nodes and type of relationships in the cypher are case sensitive, and the `match` can not find relevant nodes:

```
:person != :Person
```

So you need to fix query and repeat the creation of relations:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///friends1k\\friendship.csv" AS row
MATCH (p1:person {personID: row.pfrom})
MATCH (p2:person {personID: row.pto})
MERGE (p1)-[:FRIENDSHIP]->(p2);
```

Comment: thank you very much. I missed that. I have some illness with my eyes and sometimes miss such errors. I will try it later again with the correction.